# Javascript code in a Rails partial gets executed every time if placed inside of $(document).ready()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, turbolinks

I've got a problem that JS code in my partials (Rails) that is in $(document).ready() gets executed once the partial is displayed and I continue clicking through the page.

I'm using the `jquery-turbolinks` gem.

If I reload the page, the JS code in partials is not executed anymore (if current view does not contain the partial).

Any ideas? I'd probably have to disable the 'page:load' event that gets added from `jquery-turbolinks`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK to execute JS code on page reload with turbolinks you need to use `$(window).bind 'page:change'` instead of $(document).ready

Comment: Yeah, the problem is the code is getting executed in the ready block but I don't want it to do so. :) It's like once the partial is rendered, the Js code get's appended to the global ready block and is executed on all page:change/page:load events, even if the partial is not rendered anymore.